# The name 'model' does not exist in current context - Only on one page at one variable

Tags: asp.net, razor

So this "The name 'model' does not exist in current context" error is pretty common. However, I might have a different kind of cause.

In my view I use multiple model.variablename variables. However on one line it doesn't work:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Pw, new { @value = Model.Pw})
```

As were

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
```

Just works.

I've tried many, if not all, possible solutions. Nothing worked. However, to exclude it here's part my webconfig (main):

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

And the webconfig in my Views folder:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" /> 
        <add namespace="WingLok" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I'm using ASP.NET version 4.6, MVC5, Visual Studio 2012 and Razor 3.0 on a Windows 10 computer, to make all information complete.

Answer (score 1):

`@model` won't work.

The reason you place `@` in front is if you are using C# syntax e.g.

`Html.InputFor(model => model.Name, new { class = "something" }`

will fail because `class` is a reserved word. So you need:

`Html.InputFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "something" }`

which is correct. Now, based on that logic, the Razor compiler is looking for an object instance named `model` to parse this:

`@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Pw, new { @value = @model.Pw})`

Side-note, I don't think you need `@` in front of `value`.

It cannot find any instance named `model` so it errors.

In the lambda for `@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Pw,....` the `model` is an argument that exists in the context of that labda expression. It is not available elsewhere on that line of code. Hence the reason why you are getting the error.

To fix the problem, try

`@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Pw, new { @value = Model.Pw})`

The variable `Model` should be available everywhere in the Razor file. `Model` is the actual viewmodel that has been passed to the view itself.

EDIT:

Here is some code I tried which works fine for me

**ViewModel**

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new HomeIndexViewModel();

        viewModel.Name = "Hello World!";

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

**Razor View**

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeIndexViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { data_name = Model.Name })
```

When I view the web page, I see a input box with "Hello World!" in it. Also, here's the HTML for that field:

`<input data-name="Hello World!" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="Hello World!">`

As you can see, my custom data attribute `data-name` has also been populated correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I do what you said (changing @model.Pw to Model.Pw) I get the following error: CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'.

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code that you have tried please?

Comment: Updated. Honestly the only change was @model.Pw to Model.Pw.

Comment: Try remove all your view code to just two lines, like in my example. What happens then? Does the code work?

Comment: If I strip the code down to those two lines (the using line and @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { value = Model.Password, @class = "form-control" })) it works. So it must have something to do with other code? How?

Comment: I fixed this. I made a variable just below the using Model. var pw = Model.Pw. I was able to use pw in the password box! Thanks for your help anyway!